# No sex please, we are British!

Tags: popular-refrains

This well-renowned saying was celebrated in the 70's and 80's in London West End.

But what is its origin? What roots in popular culture has this phrase?

Comment: There is a book from George Mikes How to be an Alien (1946) with shortest chapter ever:
Continental people have sex lives: the English have hot water bottles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[No Sex Please, We're British](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Sex_Please,_We%27re_British)* was a long running comedy in British theatre (1971 - 1983), written by Alistair Foot and Anthony Marriott. It was later made into a [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070450/).

SUPPLEMENT:

There is a reference in a 1963 edition of *[Bookmarks](http://books.google.com/books?id=uLREAQAAIAAJ&q=%22no%20sex%20please%22&dq=%22no%20sex%20please%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0fg7U7bSK-HQsQTV2YDwCg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwATgo)*, a literary periodical, reporting on the banning in Ireland of Helen Gurly Browm's book, *Sex and the Single Girl*. The headine read, **No Sex, Please, in Ireland.**

An [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no%20sex%20please&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,no%20sex%20please;,c0) of *No sex please* does not seem to indicate any earlier references.